# Is there a good tutorial or example that shows the combination of protobuf-net and zeromq?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, zeromq

Is there a good tutorial or example that shows how to use protobuf-net and zeromq together? Maybe a sample client / server application showing this usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a very specific pairing. I would instead focus on two questions:

- how do I transfer a `byte[]` via zeromq?
- how do I use protobuf with a `byte[]`?

The answer to the second is: via `MemoryStream`; either create a `new MemoryStream(bytes)` (deserialization), or (serialization) create an empty `MemoryStream`, write to it, then call `ToArray()`.

I don't know much about zeromq, but most buses make this easy. If it *only* handles strings, then use Convert.ToBase64String() and Convert.FromBase64String().

Comment: ZeroMQ handles `byte[]` so hooking it up with Protobuf.Net is a simple but very powerful combination.